# Multi-Homed Host Doesn't Send Packets to Gateway

Tags: linux, networking

I've written a Python script to assist with segmentation testing that works by sending packets from one network interface to another network interface on the same host. Each interface is attached to a different network segment with proper ACLs implemented via firewall. But it seems like the OS (Kali Linux) never sends the packets to the gateway and just routes them locally. Wireshark captures the packets locally but my pfsense firewall never receives them.

Is there a way to force the packets to leave the host and be routed by the pfsense box?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Basically a duplicate of http://serverfault.com/questions/127636/force-local-ip-traffic-to-an-external-interface

Comment: Thank you Jay, I'll search harder next time.